# Setting Up a SharePoint Development Environment

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I have reformatted my machine and am running Window 7 Ultimate (64-bit). I anticipate needing to do some SharePoint development. I'm currently in the process of installing my software. I've read this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx). However, what the article doesn't tell me is which order I need to install the following:

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Visual Studio 2010
- SharePoint 2010
- Office 2010

Can anyone tell me which order I need to install these items in? I want to make sure that I get it right. Normally, I would do SQL Server 2008 R2, Visual Studio 2010, Office 2010 However, with SharePoint 2010 thrown into the mix, I'm not sure what the order should be. Can anyone provide some insight?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, one I should've asked before setting up SharePoint. I recall wishing I had installed VS prior to SharePoint, and the database has to exist for SharePoint to use, so I would recommend:

1.) Office
2.) Visual Studio
3.) SQL Server
4.) SharePoint

Also, you have the advantage of Windows 7. Create a step-named restore point before each installation (it will save you loads of trouble if you have to back up). In fact, if I were in your position I'd create a restore point and try the [Easy Setup Script](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23415) they link in that MSDN article. Good luck, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server before Sharepoint.
Rest in any order.